# How to enable inter container communication using podman-compose

Tags: docker-compose, podman

we basically have a docker-compose.yml file looking like this:

```
services:
  db:
    image: db
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    networks:
      - com
  backend:
    image: backend
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      # Lookup host of db on docker-compose network
      - DB_HOST=db:7687
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - com
networks:
  com: {}
```

When I am starting my containers using `docker-compose up` on my local machine where I use `docker` as a backend I can see that the backend can actually lookup the address of my db container.

When I am using `podman-compose up` or `docker-compose up` in combination with the `podman` backend to do the same, the host cannot be resolved. I thought that podman would handle inter container communication by creating a network for the containers like docker-compose does. Am I doing something wrong?

I just checked and podman did not create a pod for the containers to run in.  I assumed that it would create one pod to run all containers in by default. That way the containers should at least be able to reach each other via localhost. But as there is no pod, localhost isn't working, too. Does somebody know what the problem is?

Comment: Which Podman version do you use? (You could run `podman --version` to check it). I see now that you use podman-compose instead of running docker-compose with podman as the backend. I would guess that using docker-compose with a podman backend would have better chance to work.

Comment: Using docker-compose doesnt seem to change anything. I am running podman version ```3.0.2-dev```. Shouldnt the containers be able to communicate A) via localhost (as they should be running in one pod) or B) via the ```com``` network?

Comment: It looks like upgrading to a newer Podman version fixed the problem. https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/11457#issuecomment-916260531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to a newer Podman version did fix the problem. For more details take a look at this Github issue: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/11457#issuecomment-916260531